# django oscar doesnt pick up customizations

Tags: django, django-oscar

I've forked address app and created a new models and `forms.py` file.

While overriding base `AbstractAddress model` cause I didn't need the phone number mix in and a couple of other options.

Problem is that oscar only picks up the model file customization and gives the following error while loading the wrong form class from oscar

```
     raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (postcode, country, line4, line2, line3, line1) specified for UserAddress
```

Comment: I think you'll have to rewrite all the forms where the mixin is used. I mean other oscar apps not only address app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you forgot to add `from oscar.apps.address.models import *` at end of forked address app model.py file